# Code coverage of Meteor application using meteor-coverage

Tags: meteor

I am working on a Meteor application and we need to generate code coverage reports. For this, I am trying to configure [meteor-coverage](https://github.com/serut/meteor-coverage).

Following is my configuration in `settings.coverage.json` file.

```
{
    "coverage": {
        "coverage_app_folder": "D:\\my\\app\\path\\",
        "is_coverage_active": true,
        "verbose": true
     }
}
```

and I am running the following command to generate the coverage report.

```
meteor --settings settings.coverage.json
```

The problem I am facing is that I am getting the coverage only for some files in the application. There is a lot of code that is executed when I run the application but that isn't reflecting in the report.

My question is if I am going in the right direction or is there any other configuration that will help my cause.